# Julia: How to compute convolution of vectors containing NaNs?

Tags: julia, convolution

The convolution function in Julia has the following behaviour:

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.6.1 (2017-10-24 22:15 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

julia> conv([1,2,NaN],[1])

3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
```

Is this a bug? Or is this related to the FFT Algorithm used by `conv`?

How can I compute a convolution in Julia (not manually for performance reasons) if one of the vectors contains `NaN`s? In this example, the result should be:

```
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
   1.0
   2.0
 NaN
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the `conv` function in julia uses the FFT.

What do you mean "not manually"? Writing your own convolution function in julia should still be fast.

e.g.

```
 function native_conv{T,V}(u::Array{T,1}, v::Array{V,1})
       m = length(u)
       n = length(v)
       w = zeros(promote_type(T,V), m+n-1)
       @inbounds begin
       for j in 1:m, k in 1:n
           w[j+k-1] += u[j]*v[k]
       end;end
       return w
  end
```

Or this might be faster (do the conv with FFT with NaNs set to zero then re-normalize).

**Edit: it's faster when `v` (filter) is large**.

```
function nanconv{T}(u::Array{T,1},v)
        nans = find(isnan, u)
        u = copy(u)
        u[nans] .= zero(T) # set nans2zero
        pass1 = conv(u,v)  # do convolution
        u[u.>0] .= one(T)   # 
        norm = conv(u,v)   # get normalizations (also gets rid of edge effects)
        u[:] .= one(T)     #
        norm .= norm./(conv(u,v)) # put edge effects back
        w = pass1 ./ norm       # normalize
        reshaped_nans = reshape_nans(nans,length(v))
        w[reshaped_nans] .= NaN           # reset Nans
        return w
end

function reshape_nans(nans,lv)
       out = zeros(Int, length(nans)*lv)
       j = 1;
       inc = lv - 1
       for i in nans
           inds = i:(i+inc)
           out[j:j+inc] = inds
           j += inc + 1 
       end
       out
end
```

Comment: The `native_conv` seems to work! By "not manually" I mean that I was taught in a numerics course that one should never try implement matrix multiplication or convolution oneself because it would be much slower than the highly optimized BLAS/FFT functions. But for my purposes your `native_conv` function is sufficiently fast.

Comment: @phinz if your filter becomes large then the `nanconv` implementation will be much faster I think, otherwise the native one is good.

Comment: Argh missing another increment... Turns out its really difficult to write code without being able to test it... I'm now 90% confident it will work...

Comment: Replacing NaNs with 0 will fix the issue numerically, but how significant are the effects on the accuracy of the resultant convolution? Compare with `astropy` for example which interpolates over missing/NaN numbers: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.convolution.convolve.html